# Reactjs not recognize some of the ES6 function?

Tags: reactjs, es6-modules

I am new in Reactjs, I tried to use ES6 code in my `React.js` file like the following, the compiler not recognized filter and includes?

Error :

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of 
    undefined(reading 'filter')...
```

```js
    const noStoreName = csvFile.filter( e => categoriesFile.includes(e))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it's not from compiler

cvsFile is probebly  undefiend

so simply add question mark  or set if condition

```
const noStoreName = csvFile?.filter( e => categoriesFile.includes(e))
```

or :

```
if(csvFile){
  const noStoreName = csvFile.filter( e => categoriesFile.includes(e))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not ES6 issue, it is happening because of your csvFile array is **empty or undefined** in initial, you can do like this:

```
const noStoreName = csvFile && csvFile.length > 0 && csvFile.filter(e => categoriesFile.includes(e))
```

If you want to use **optional chaining** then like this:

```
const noStoreName = csvFile?.filter( e => categoriesFile?.includes(e))
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask you why the csvFile returns undefined but when I console.log(results.data), it shows the data?  const csvFile = Papa.parse(e.target.files[0], {
            header: true,
            skipEmptyLines: true,
            complete: function (results) {
             return results.data
              //console.log(results.data)
            },
          });

Comment: It returns undefined at initial time or first time.